Unhandled error when running vitest in DevContainer
In my company we moved to DevContainer. I had few PACT test that I am running with vitest.
Theses tests are run and pass in local environment but as soon as I moved to DevContainer I am getting the following error when running tests wit the same command :
Command to run tests :
vitest run src/contract-test/consumer/action-consumer.test.ts

Error :
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Error ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at get hasIndices [as hasIndices] (<anonymous>)
    at get flags [as flags] (<anonymous>)
    at String.matchAll (<anonymous>)
    at _searchLast (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38476:34)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38483:40)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38509:12)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38509:12)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38509:12)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38509:12)
    at _interpolate (file:///app/.yarn/__virtual__/vite-virtual-68526d8c1a/0/cache/vite-npm-5.0.11-d5457a8b86-74a3ddc6d4.zip/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:38509:12)


I have found the root reason for this :
When in devcontainer, make sure to not add in your .env file a variable then assign the same name to it :
API_TOKEN=${API_TOKEN}

This will cause the error inly in devcontainer in local it will work fine.
